# Analytical proof of an equation that includes transcendental functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, transcendence

Can anyone help me find an analytical proof for the following statement:
for
$$t \in ]0,1[\setminus\{t_0\},\quad t' \in ]0,1[\setminus\{t_0\},\quad t\neq t',\quad k_1,k_2 \in \mathbf{R}^*,\quad t_0 \in ]0,1[,
$$
is true that
$$t = 
\frac{1}{k_2}\ln\left(\frac{(e^{k_2t_0} - 1)(e^{-k_2(t'-1)} - 1) }{e^{-k_2(t_0 - 1)}-1} + 1\right) 
= 
\frac{1}{k_1}\ln\left(\frac{(e^{k_1t_0} - 1)(e^{-k_1(t'-1)} - 1) }{e^{-k_1(t_0 - 1)}-1} + 1\right) 
$$
implies that either
$$
k_1 = k_2
        \quad \text{or}\quad
        t_0 = \frac{1}{2}\text{ ?}
$$

Thank you in advance!